# QT UIC does not automatically append the headers for custom widgets

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qt-designer

i made a custom widget "DuwagWidget" and custom widget plugin "DuwagWidgetPlugin"  which can be dragged&dropped inside qt designer to create my duwag.ui file.

However, when i try to compile my program, the ui_duwag.h is generated from the QT user interface compiler, but in this auto generated file, the uic does not include my "DuwagWidget.h" which is necessary to create the custom widget class.

The DuwagWidgetPlugin is (derived from the Interface in QT to create CustomWidgets) simply a factory class for the DuwagWidget.

Here is the code from the DuwagWidgetPlugin :^

```
    #include <DuwagWidgetPlugin.h>
    #include <QtPlugin>
    #include <qwidget.h>
    #include <MTBFWidget.h>


    DuwagWidgetPlugin::DuwagWidgetPlugin( QObject *parent ) : QObject(parent) {
        initialized = false;
    }

    void DuwagWidgetPlugin::initialize(QDesignerFormEditorInterface * /* core */) {

        if (initialized)
            return;
        initialized = true;
     }

    bool DuwagWidgetPlugin::isInitialized() const {
        return initialized;
    }

    QWidget *DuwagWidgetPlugin::createWidget(QWidget *parent) {
        return new DuwagWidget( parent );
    }

    QString DuwagWidgetPlugin::name() const {
        return "DuwagWidget";
    }

    QString DuwagWidgetPlugin::group() const {
        return "duwagplugin";
    }

    QIcon DuwagWidgetPlugin::icon() const {
        return QIcon();
    }

    QString DuwagWidgetPlugin::toolTip() const {
        return "The duwag control panel";
    }

    QString DuwagWidgetPlugin::whatsThis() const {
        return "The duwag Control panel";
    }

    bool DuwagWidgetPlugin::isContainer() const {
        return false;
    }

    QString DuwagWidgetPlugin::domXml() const {
        return  "<widget class=\"DuwagWidget\" name=\"DuwagWidget\">\n"
                    " <property name=\"geometry\">\n"
                "  <rect>\n"
                "   <x>0</x>\n"
                "   <y>0</y>\n"
                "   <width>100</width>\n"
                "   <height>100</height>\n"
                "  </rect>\n"
                " </property>\n"
                " <property name=\"toolTip\" >\n"
                "  <string>The MTBF Control panel</string>\n"
                " </property>\n"
                " <property name=\"whatsThis\" >\n"
                "  <string>The MTBF Control panel.</string>\n"
                " </property>\n"
                "</widget>\n";
    }

    QString DuwagWidgetPlugin::includeFile() const {
        return "DuwagWidget.h";
    }

    Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(duwagplugin, DuwagWidgetPlugin)
```

So the problem is, in the generated header file, it cannot make a custom widget "DuwagWidget" because it does not know what it is..

Comment: i solved this issue by adding something to my cmake..i missed the include directory, so if someone uses CMAKE and has the same problem, add this to your cmake : include_directories(INCLUDEPATH)

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem when including custom classes in a QtDesigner .ui file.  `uic` does an *okay* job of adding the appropriate headers when you use the "Promote to.." option.

1. Right-click on any widget in your layout.
2. Select "Promote to..".
3. Select the base class and type the name of the promoted class "NewClass".  It automatically adds a `#include "NewClass.h"` to the file "ui_yourclass.h".

Unfortunately, this creates redundant include warnings when another designer file accesses the same custom class and both "ui_yourclass.h" files are included from the same header.  Also, the need to promote a widget makes it mandatory for you to create and initialize one instance of that class within your designer layout file.

Another way, which I've read about, is to go to Tools > Form Editor > Form Settings and add "NewClass.h" in the sections entitled "Include Hints".  But I have never done it this way.